# Is there any universal way to mark function as not returning

Tags: c, function

When I simplify the example.. I have a function like:

```
void Crash(void) {
    exit(100);
}
```

And somewhere else code like:

```
...
if (val == NULL) Crash();
*val = something; // here I get the dereferencing NULL pointer warning
```

Is there any way how to *mark* the `Crash` function as *escaping*? So I would not have to write:

```
if (val == NULL) {
    Crash();
    return; // to avoid compiler's warnings
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since C11 there is `_Noreturn` and also `#include <stdnoreturn.h>` which comes with `noreturn` macro.

```
#include <stdnoreturn.h>

noreturn void Crash(void);
```